# Accepting raw JSON Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a asp.net core method, I want it to accept RAW json, I do not and will not always know the schema of the json object, so I am using `dynamic types` with dot notation.

This method works when I string the json escaping each character. I have tried to use the json body directly, but this did not work. So it seems my option were to `Serialize` and then `Deserialize` the json. ( very redundant) but it seems to throw error any other way if I try to use the JSON body directly.

In the debugger, everything seems to work with the Serialize and Deserialize of the object / string, but throws an error on the id(property) when I try to cast the object to string and gives the error. (In the debugger I am able to see the Id correctly though).

`({Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot convert type 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement' to 'string')}`

I really do not see why it gives the type as a string yet cannot convert it. I have even tried to remove the casting, and still receive this error.

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] ExpandoObject requestInput)
{
    try
    {
//Makes a JSON String
        var stringObject = (string) JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestInput);
        DateTime time = DateTime.UtcNow;
// Recreated the Json Object
        dynamic requestObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(stringObject); 
// Throws Error here, yet it shows Value as the correct Id number (Value: Type String)
        string reqObject = (string) requestObject.Id;
```

Comment: If you always know the object is going to have certain properties (such as an Id) then why not just describe the parts of the object that are consistent as a class definition? The deserializer will happily discard the extra parts from the JSON.

Comment: have you tried JObject?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane `JObject` would not make sense since he's using `System.Text.Json`, not `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: RIght just noticed. but `System.Text.Json` has an equivalent too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there is no support for `ExpandoObject` in .NET Core, yet. MS says that maybe it will be added in .NET 5.0. Until then, you can use this `JsonConverter` I [found on a thread](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29690). I will post the code here in case that thread goes away.

You can use it like this:

```
[HttpPost, Route("testPost")]
public IActionResult TestPost([FromBody] object obj) // just use "object"
{
    // object is: { "hello":"world" }

    var myDynamic = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj), new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            Converters = { new DynamicJsonConverter() }
        });

    var test = (string)myDynamic.hello;
    // test will equal "world"

    return Ok();
}
```

Here is the converter:

```
/// <summary>
/// Temp Dynamic Converter
/// by:tchivs@live.cn
/// </summary>
public class DynamicJsonConverter : JsonConverter<dynamic>
{
    public override dynamic Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.True)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.False)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Number)
        {
            if (reader.TryGetInt64(out long l))
            {
                return l;
            }

            return reader.GetDouble();
        }

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            if (reader.TryGetDateTime(out DateTime datetime))
            {
                return datetime;
            }

            return reader.GetString();
        }

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            using JsonDocument documentV = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
            return ReadObject(documentV.RootElement);
        }
        // Use JsonElement as fallback.
        // Newtonsoft uses JArray or JObject.
        JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
        return document.RootElement.Clone();
    }

    private object ReadObject(JsonElement jsonElement)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach (var obj in jsonElement.EnumerateObject())
        {
            var k = obj.Name;
            var value = ReadValue(obj.Value);
            expandoObject[k] = value;
        }
        return expandoObject;
    }
    private object? ReadValue(JsonElement jsonElement)
    {
        object? result = null;
        switch (jsonElement.ValueKind)
        {
            case JsonValueKind.Object:
                result = ReadObject(jsonElement);
                break;
            case JsonValueKind.Array:
                result = ReadList(jsonElement);
                break;
            case JsonValueKind.String:
                //TODO: Missing Datetime&Bytes Convert
                result = jsonElement.GetString();
                break;
            case JsonValueKind.Number:
                //TODO: more num type
                result = 0;
                if (jsonElement.TryGetInt64(out long l))
                {
                    result = l;
                }
                break;
            case JsonValueKind.True:
                result = true;
                break;
            case JsonValueKind.False:
                result = false;
                break;
            case JsonValueKind.Undefined:
            case JsonValueKind.Null:
                result = null;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private object? ReadList(JsonElement jsonElement)
    {
        IList<object?> list = new List<object?>();
        foreach (var item in jsonElement.EnumerateArray())
        {
            list.Add(ReadValue(item));
        }
        return list.Count == 0 ? null : list;
    }
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        object value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

### Edited To Add:

Here is a much slicker way to handle `dynamic` using the converter above as pointed out by [Aluan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915893/aluan-haddad) in the comments. In your `Startup.cs` class, add this:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DynamicJsonConverter()));
```

Then you don't have to do any goofy stuff in your controller. You can just set the body parameter as dynamic and it magically works:

```
[HttpPost, Route("testPost")]
public IActionResult TestPost([FromBody] dynamic obj)
{
    // object is: { "hello":"world" }

    var test = (string)obj.hello;
    // test will equal "world"

    return Ok();
}
```

Way nicer!

Comment: If you add this converter when calling `AddJsonOptions`, you could make the parameter `dynamic` I believe.

Comment: @AluanHaddad -- holy cow that works. I am going to update my answer